# Javascript Countdown timer does not work

Tags: javascript

I came across this codepen https://codepen.io/donovanh/pen/JWdyEm, and I was trying to apply it to an older countdown timer I did because this one seemed better.. If I set the countdown date to today then it still says there is 30 days left.

Here is the code where it calculates the difference between dates.

```js
function daysBetween( date1, date2 ) {
  //Get 1 day in milliseconds
  var one_day=1000*60*60*24;

  // Convert both dates to milliseconds
  var date1_ms = date1.getTime();
  var date2_ms = date2.getTime();

  // Calculate the difference in milliseconds
  var difference_ms = date2_ms - date1_ms;

  // Convert back to days and return
  return Math.round(difference_ms/one_day); 
}

console.log("Days to end of April = " +
  daysBetween(new Date(), new Date("2018-04-30")));
```

I cannot figure out where the extra days are coming from, any help would be appreciated, thanks

Comment: Provide an [mcve]. What input are you giving this function? What output do you expect? What output do you get?

Comment: how do you set countdown to today ? please add some more explanation

Comment: if i were you i would create a simple js fiddle for it, to help others in their effort to help me! Its a simple case, make a fiddle for it

Comment: I've just updated you question to include a running snippet, & just made it calculate to the end of April, can you update to show the problem your getting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that your problem comes from giving wrong month number as argument to `Date.UTC`. According to docs https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/UTC, month is a 0-11 number. If you would like to call function for todays date, you have to call it like `new Date(2018, 3, 10, 12, 15)`.

Answer (score 1):

Months start from 0 and go to 11.

The end of April is `Date("2018-03-30")`, not `Date("2018-04-30")`  that is why you get extra 30 or 31 days